# Product shouldnt store MySQL if there no value

Tags: php, mysql, report, store

I have entry table Like following format in php.. The 'product' row is fetch from MySQL table. Hence it will display all list in entry page.

```
Date.  Product.  New stock sale 
1-1-12. Xyzzy.      6      1
1-1-12. Yyyyy.      0.      0
1-1-12. Hjjjjj.     O.      O
1-1-12.  Ddddd.     5.      2
```

When I add these entries to will store on my MySQL database. I don't want to add product "yyyyy and "hjjjjj" because it has no value. Both product 0 values. I dont need to add these product in my MySQL database. It should add Like below in SQL.

```
Date.  Product.  New stock sale 
1-1-12. Xyzzy.      6       1
1-1-12.  Ddddd.     5.      2
```

Comment: Will be easier to answer if you show the code where you insert these into the database. Probably wrap in an "if" statement, but we're guessing without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  * from tableName
WHERE   `NewStock` !=0  or   `Sale` != 0
```

Comment: I don't need to fetch report from database. When I entry these values , it shouldnt save SQL If newsrock and sale has 0 data